# get a char inside a span of a div

Tags: gettext, getchar, textnode

```
<div id = "board_code">
 <div>
    <span>r</span>
    <span>o</span>
    <span>w</span>
    <span>1</span>
 </div>

 <div>
    <span>r</span>
    <span>o</span>
    <span>w</span>
    <span>2</span>
 </div>
</div>
```

I am trying to get the string '**2**'  to be used for comparison with char like { [ ( < ' "

I tried this:

```
alert($('#board_code > div').eq(1).eq(3).text();
output is: blank
```

When I tried this:

```
alert($('#board_code > div').eq(1).eq(0).text();
output is: row2
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$("span").last().text()
```

That could work, but I'm not sure if it's good enough for your needs.

http://jsfiddle.net/6r2nP/1/

```
$("#board_code span").last().text()
```

That one might be better.

http://jsfiddle.net/6r2nP/2/

Comment: thanks but i need to loop around the spans, that would look like: $('#board_code > div').eq(outerloop).eq(innerloop).text()

Comment: Got it ^^. $('#board_code_dup > div').eq(1).children().eq(3).text()

Comment: Glad I could help! Good you found your answer!